# JQuery Carousel stop after a circle

Tags: jquery, carousel, caroufredsel

I install this [carousel](http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/) on my site. The problem is that after a complete circle, when the carousel get back to the first page, the transitions stopped and buttons for back and next don't work anymore. This happens only if I set the autoplay to true.

Probably this is a configuration option but I cannot find anything on the documentation. Any help?

Comment: yeah make your own plugin! this one is a gas factory & it'll take you more time to tweak it than to make your own specific to your requirements

Comment: The problem is that my skills on jquery is far far away from zero and the only solution is to use a ready-to-go plugin.